# Simply generated sequences with mysterious differences

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, recurrences

Suppose that $a_0 < a_1,$ $b_0 < b_1,$ and $$a_n=a_1b_{n-1}+a_0b_{n-2}+qn+r$$ for $n \geq 2$, where $a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1,q,r$ are integers such that $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are increasing and ${(|a_n|)}$ and ${(|b_n|)}$ partition the positive integers. What can be proved about the cardinality of $$D=\{(a_n-a_{n-1},b_n-b_{n-1})\},$$ for $n \geq 0?$

Experimental results:

1. If $(a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1,q,r)=(-1,2,3,4,2,0)$, then $|D|=9$; see "Experimental fact" at [A possibly surprising appearance of $\sqrt{2}.$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290808/a-possibly-surprising-appearance-of-sqrt2?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. If $(a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1,q,r)=(1,2,3,4,1,0)$, then $D=\{(1,1),(4,1),(4,2),(5,1),(6,1),(11,1)\}.$
3. If $(a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1,q,r)=(3,4,1,2,1,-7)$, then $D=\{(1,1),(2,3),(8,1),(8,2),(11,1),(12,1),(16,2),(18,1)\}.$

Reasons for studying the set $D$ include these related questions:

1. Is $(a_n-a_{n-1})$ ever linearly recurrent?
2. Let $d$ be a number that occurs infinitely many times in $(b_n-b_{n-1})$, and let $(p_n)$ be the sequence of numbers $k$ such that $b_k-b_{k-1}=d.$ Must $(p_n/n)$ converge? As an example, for $(a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1,q,r)=(-1,2,3,4,2,0)$, we have 
   $$(p_n) = (1,11,13,16,19,22,25,28,31,34,37,43,45,51,53,56,62,\dots),$$
   and it appears that $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n/n = 1+\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: In Example 1, it is not clear $a_0=-1$, since it is required that $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ make a partition of the positive integers. After all, is there a reason why the coefficients in front of $b_{n-1}$ and $b_{n-2}$ must be exactly $a_1$ and $a_0$ and not some other integers $p$ and $s$ like $q$ and $r$?

Comment: Pietro - As a quick fix, I added absolute values.

Comment: I agree with @Pietro in that it might be more convenient to keep them all positive and set $a_n=e_1a_1b_{n-1}+e_0a_0b_{n-2}+qn+r$ with $e_0,e_1=\pm1$ (or maybe even more general)

Comment: I think in example 1 we have $|D|=8$, I cannot see $(1,1)$ occurring.

Comment: @MartinRubey In the referred question it was formulated differently, with $a_0=1$ and $a_n=a_1b_{n-1}\color{red}{-}a_0b_{n-2}+2n$, then it started with $a_*=(1,2,9,12,...)$ and $b_*=(3,4,5,6,...)$. Not really essential, I believe the main thing is to explain why the set of possible differences is finite.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Yes, I agree.

Comment: Is it (intuitively) clear that $|D|$ is also finite for longer "convolutions", eg. $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^2 a_k b_{n-3+k} + qn + r$?

Comment: @MartinRubey Since $a_n-a_{n-1}=a_0(b_{n-1}-b_{n-2})+a_1(b_{n-2}-b_{n-3})+a_2(b_{n-3}-b_{n-4})+q$, arguing as in Pietro Majer's answer, if almost all $a_n−a_{n-1}$ are $>1$ then almost all $b_n−b_{n-1}$ are either $1$ or $2$, so that there are only finitely many possibilities for $a_n−a_{n−1}$. It is however not entirely clear what happens if (and how) infinitely many $a_n−a_{n-1}$ are $1$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is less more than a long comment. It seems that a somehow simpler case is the  when $a_{n+1}-a_n>1$ (at least eventually) which means $b_{n+1}-b_n\in\{1,2\}$ (eventually), and  $a_{n+1}-a_n$ takes values in a finite set $\mathcal{A}$ of say $r$ integers greater or equal to $2$. Then the sequence  $a_{n+1}-a_n$ is generated by a substitution map (like in the one described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290220/limit-associated-with-complementary-sequences) or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290808/a-possibly-surprising-appearance-of-sqrt2?noredirect=1&lq=1), so that the entire sequence $a_{n+1}-a_n$, seen as an infinite string, has the form $p\cdot\tau(p)\cdot\tau(p)^2\cdot\tau(p)^3\dots$, where the dots stand  for concatenation of words, and $p$ is a prefix. For such a substitution map $\tau$  one can write an associated $r\times r$ transition matrix $A:=(a_{ij})$ for the number of occurrences of each symbol in a transformed word: let $a_{ij}$ denote the number of  occurrences of the letter $s_i$ in the word $\tau(s_j)$. Then, if in the vector $X$, $X_i$ is the number of occurrences of  $s_i$ in a given word $w$,  the coordinates of $AX$ give the number of occurrences of each $s_i$ in the word $\tau(w)$, so that, for $w=p$, the vector $A^k X$ gives the distribution of letters in $\tau(p^k)$; the length of  $\tau(p^k)$ is the sum of coordinates of $A^{k-1} X$. This way the various asymptotics of $a_n$ can be easily related to the spectrum of $A$; in fact one use the standard techniques of  finite Markov chains introducing a suitable Markov chain deduced from the map $\tau$. For instance, both quoted cases can be treated this way.

The case when $a_{n+1}-a_n$ can take the value $1$ frequently, so that $b_{n+1}-b_n$ assumes more values, seems less clear to me, but it may possibly be studied in the same lines.